# Symfony 5 - Twig - Access entity.entityB.entityC.property cost many requests

Tags: php, symfony, request, doctrine, relation

on one of my pages, I display a list of clients, with information such as their country, or the name of their company.

So I proceeded as follows:

Repository :

```php
    public function findAllAvailableCustomers()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->join('s.user', 'u')
            ->join('u.entreprise', 'e')
            ->leftJoin('s.subscription', 'ss')
            ->leftJoin('ss.plan', 'sp')
            ->addSelect('ss')
            ->where('e.willBeDeleted = false')
            ->orderBy('s.createdAt', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

Twig :

```
//...

<td>{{ customer.user.email }}</td>
<td>{{ customer.denomination }}</td>
<td>{{ customer.user.entreprise.nom }}</td> // generates 11 requests

//...
```

I don't understand how I could alleviate the number of queries caused by displaying the client's company name.

I tried to add `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"` at `StripeCustomer.user` and `User.entreprise` entity properties but nothing.

I tried also to add this at the request :

`->addSelect('u, e, ss')` but it generates 600 requests more

SO I don't know... :/

Comment: You could try writing SQL directly and then map the result to your entity using the ResultSetMappingBuilder (see: [Native SQL in Docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/native-sql.html#resultsetmappingbuilder)) or you could create a DTO specific to that page, where you fetch the data and store it in a flat object (see [SELECT NEW](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#new-operator-syntax)). Hope that helps

Comment: It really depends on your data model and how things are joined. Sometimes it is just easier to create a second query for a more expensive object. In this case, can you just make a second request for the specific "enterprise", and then instead of `customer.user.entreprise.nom` you'd just use `entreprise.nom`

Comment: Thanks to both of you I'll explore these ideas!

Answer (score 1):

You should also select the enterprise entity in your first query:

```
public function findAllAvailableCustomers()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->join('s.user', 'u')
        ->join('u.entreprise', 'e')
        ->leftJoin('s.subscription', 'ss')
        ->leftJoin('ss.plan', 'sp')
        ->addSelect('e') // <--- HERE
        ->addSelect('ss')
        ->where('e.willBeDeleted = false')
        ->orderBy('s.createdAt', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```